# Eloquent JS ch6 Pet cat exercise

Tags: javascript, oop

it's my first time using stack overflow.
I just wanna make simple pet cat using below exercise from college assignment.
Code works fine, but not so sure if my code answers the portion of decreasing the
object properties. I would really appreciate if I can get some feedback on make it better.
I am coding newbie. Thank you.

//question
Write yourself a virtual cat - animals with a CLI are so much nicer than ones with fur.

### Create an object that represents a cat. It should have properties for tiredness, hunger, loneliness, and happiness
Next, write methods that increase and decrease those properties. Call them something that actually represents what would increase or decrease these things, like "feed", "sleep", or "pet".
Last, write a method that prints out the cat's status in each area. (Be creative e.g. Paws is really hungry, Paws is VERY happy.)

//my code

```
let cat=  {
name: "Roy",
tiredness:0,
hunger:0,
loneliness:0,
happiness:0,
//increase
feed: function(fullness){
  let x= fullness + this.hunger
  console.log(`${this.name} is ${x} %  full `)
},
energized:function (hour){
  let x= hour+this.tiredness
  console.log(`${this.name} is ${x} %  energized `)
},
socialLife:function(hangout){
  let x= hangout+this.happiness
  console.log(`${this.name} is ${x} %  happy `)
},
//decrease
feedMinus:function(gettingHungry){
  let x= gettingHungry-this.hunger
  console.log(`${this.name} is getting ${x} %  hungry `)
},
sleep:function (gettingSleepy){
  let x= gettingSleepy-this.tiredness
  console.log(`${this.name} is getting ${x} %  sleepy `)
},
isolated:function(alone){
  let x= alone-this.happiness
  console.log(`${this.name} is getting ${x} %  isolated `)
}
}
```

Comment: Your question belongs more on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods never change the values of your properties.

Try this instead:

```
feed: function(fullness) {
  this.hunger += fullness;
  console.log(`${this.name} is ${this.hunger} %  full`);
}
```

Maybe you should add some limitations to your values, like hunger can't be less than 0% nor more than 100%. Use Math.max() and Math.min().